# How to best deal with this Python numerical error?

Tags: python, math, floating-point

I have this code that throws a `math domain error` exception:

```
v = -1.0

for i in range (201):
    print acos (v)
    v += 0.01
```

But if I change it to this, it works:

```
v = -100

for i in range (201):
    print acos (v / 100.0)
    v += 1
```

Is this because of rounding?

How to best solve this in Python? Or should I just do it like my last example?

Comment: Looks like a mathematical problem to me. Did you check if `acos` supports your inputs?

Comment: I don't know if you can see, but the second code is doing something different than the first one...

Comment: Sorry fixed the last line in the first example.

Comment: Yes, it is because of rounding.  The floating point number `0.01` is actually a little bigger than `0.01`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do:

```
>>> format(0.01, '.30f')
'0.010000000000000000208166817117'
```

you can see that `0.01` (as a floating point number with double precision) is bigger than the number `0.01` you learned at school.

So, when you sum it 100 times, the error gets bigger:

```
>>> sum([0.01]*100)
1.0000000000000007
```

And that's enough to give a math domain error.

What can you do?

- Use the second code
- `round()` it to less decimal points:

.

```
>>> round(1.0000000000000007, 13)
1.0
```

13 or 14 may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
v = -1.0
for i in range(201):
    print acos(v)
    v = round(v + 0.01, 2)
```

It will work for your question. It's the same old problem with floating point numbers: not all decimal numbers can be precisely represented in binary. Run this:

```
v = -1.0
for i in range(201):
    print repr(v), acos(v)
    v += 0.01
```

And you'll see that at the end of the loop, right before the error, `v` has a value slightly bigger than `1.0`, and *that* is what causes the `math domain error`.

Comment: it would even be better to round directly after incrementing v, so that errors don't grow over time.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark Thanks for the suggestion, I edited my answer accordingly.